# js mysql php select2.js add 2 values to dropdown one of them should to call from js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-select2

Please need a help on how to call the current select color to the selective item in the dropdown.

dropdown:

[image]

database:
[image]

php code:

```
<select data-placeholder="Escolha Categoria..." class="select-search" name="categoria_id" tabindex="2" id="category_drop">
                                    <option value="">Categoria</option>
                                    <?php foreach($categorias_produtos as $categoria_produto){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $categoria_produto->categoria_id; ?>"><?php echo $categoria_produto->categoria_nome; ?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
```

js code:

```
<script>
function format(produto) {
    if (!produto.id) return produto.text; // optgroup
    return "<em class='fa fa-circle space_for_product' style='color:<?php

    foreach($categorias_produtos as $categoria_produto){
        echo $categoria_produto->categoria_cor;
    }

    ?>'></em>" + produto.text;
}
$("#category_drop").select2({
  formatResult: format
});
```

and this is the result:

```
<div class="select2-result-label"><em class="fa fa-circle space_for_product" style="color:#ff0040;#ff4000;#00ff40;#00bfff;#ffff00;#bfff00;#4000ff;#ffbf00;#ff00bf;"></em>Farinhas</div>
```

so how to call just the correct color from database for each item in dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

to be interpreted PHP code must pass through the server.

for javascript, it's the console inside the browser who does it. So if you put some php inside Js code. it won't work.

the solution is to get the colors first and write them in an invisible block with an id then get the values later by javascript

```
 <?php 
      echo '<div id="colors" display = "none">';
      foreach ($ categorias_produtos as $ categoria_produto) {
         echo "$ categoria_produto-> categoria_cor"." ,";
     }
       echo '</ div>';
 ?>
```

then you will use :

```
<script>
        colorString = document.getElementById("colors").value;
        colorArray = colorString.split(",");
</script>
```

i wish that was usefull for you. good day.

Comment: Hi  Saadounn, thank you for your replay, actually the select2.js doesn't give facility to use the style in this way as you see i should use a function to work with .select2-result-label.  this wont to work :(

Comment: i searching for somethig like this:

Comment: Hi Saadounn, thank you so much!! your idea was really good just wanted to see how can i use it!!! thanks again